# check radiobutton state winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, radio-button

I use mingw32 compiler.
I created two radioButton:

```
radio1 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  , L"BUTTON", L"RadioButton1",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON  ,
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIOBTN1,
   GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
SendMessage(radioBtnDaily, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);

radio2 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  , L"BUTTON", L"RadioButton2",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON  ,
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIOBTN2,
   GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);

SendMessage(radio1, BM_SETCHECK , (WPARAM) font, TRUE);
SendMessage(radio2,  WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);
```

And I handle the check state, something like this:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {   
        case ID_RADIOBTN1:
        {
            MessageBoxW( NULL, "radio1 is checked", L"radio", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
        }
        break;

        case ID_RADIOBTN2:
        {
        MessageBoxW( NULL, "radio2 is checked", L"radio", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
        }
        break;
        ....
```

But this always run when I click the radiobutton so it not check the state.
How to check the state without use the click event?

Answer (score 4):

Use [IsDlgButtonChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
if(IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, ID_RADIOBTN1))
    MessageBox(NULL, "radio1 is checked")
else
    MessageBox(NULL, "radio1 is not checked")
```

Comment: It doesnt work well because it always show me "radio1 is checked". Because if I put this if-else to the `case ID_RADIOBTN1:` it run after I click the button, And Automaticly set the checkstate before run the `case ID_RADIOBTN1:` so it always shows the checked state.

Comment: `IsDlgButtonChecked()` returns the actual state - checked, indeterminate, or unchecked. You are checking the return value for `!= 0`, which will always be true for a radio button. You have to test the return value for the individual states instead, eg: `if(IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, ID_RADIOBTN1) == BST_CHECKED)`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Not exactly.  A radio button can only be checked or unchecked and BST_UNCHECKED is 0.

Comment: @Carl Mark:  I see, I did not understand your original question.  Short of subclassing the control I don't believe you can get a notification before the button state changes.

Comment: I take that back.  You can change the button style from BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON to BS_RADIOBUTTON.  The system will no longer manage the state for you so you will have to do it via CheckRadioButton or BM_SETCHECK.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `BM_GETCHECK` message, or the `Button_GetCheck()` macro, to get the radio button's actual state, eg:

```
radio1 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  , L"BUTTON", L"RadioButton1",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON  ,
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIOBTN1,
   GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
SendMessage(radio1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);

radio2 = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT  , L"BUTTON", L"RadioButton2",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON  ,
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   hwnd, (HMENU)ID_RADIOBTN2,
   GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
SendMessage(radio2,  WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);
```

.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if ((HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {   
            case ID_RADIOBTN1:
            {
                switch (Button_GetCheck(radio1))
                {
                    case BST_CHECKED:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio1 is checked", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;

                    case BST_INDETERMINATE:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio1 is indeterminate", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;

                    case BST_UNCHECKED:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio1 is unchecked", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;

            case ID_RADIOBTN2:
            {
                switch (Button_GetCheck(radio2))
                {
                    case BST_CHECKED:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio2 is checked", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;

                    case BST_INDETERMINATE:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio2 is indeterminate", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;

                    case BST_UNCHECKED:
                        MessageBoxW( NULL, L"radio2 is unchecked", L"radio", MB_OK );
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: This is exactly what IsDlgButtonChecked() does.

Comment: All `IsDlgButtonChecked()` does is sends a `BM_GETCHECK` message to the button, so it is better to do that directly, or at least with the `Button_GetCheck()` macro, when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on what event you want to check the status of the button so you need some sort of interaction (this can be another event like window minimized, resized etc or another thread checking but not modifying the state of your control)

Comment: I try but I dont find the solution yet, have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It you need to test the state of the radio button, you can use (in pascal):

```
if SendMessage(hradiobutton, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) = BST_CHECKED
```

(this for checked state).

You can replace BST_CHECKED with all the constants listed at:

[Documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-getcheck)

Please, forgive my errors.